# SAS: Calculating rolling 6-month skewness from daily returns

Tags: sql, sas, statistics

I am trying to solve the following problem in SAS.

I have data of daily returns for several stocks. This is what my data looks like (simplified):

```
PERMNO  DATE        RETURN
10078   2010JAN02   0.0500
10104   2010JAN02   -0.0190
10107   2010JAN02   0.0020
10078   2010JAN03   0.0040
10104   2010JAN03   -0.0400
10107   2010JAN03   0.0500
...       ...        ...
10078   2015JAN02   -0.0190
10104   2015JAN02   0.0100
10107   2015JAN02   0.0700
10078   2015JAN05   0.0500
10104   2010JAN03   -0.0190
10107   2010JAN03   0.0020
```

PERMNO identifies a stock, DATE identifies a date (yyyymmmdd), RETURN is the daily stock return.
I have simplified this example for only three stocks (10078, 10104, 10107).

Goal: I am trying to calculate rolling skewness for each stock i in a given month t.
I want to calculate the monthly skewness measure for each stock using the previous 6 months (i.e. months t-6 to t-1) of daily returns data. Therefore, for a stock in e.g. July 2010, I want the skewness measure for that month to be based on its daily returns from January 2010 to June 2010.

I want the output data to include PERMNO, month ID, and the monthly skewness measure (based on prior 6 months of data) for that month. Here is a a picture to illustrate the desired output I want:

```
PERMNO  DATE        6MONTH_SKEWNESS
10078   2010JUL30   0.7257
10104   2010JUL30   -0.7056
10107   2010JUL30   -0.6781
10078   2010AUG31   0.9999
10104   2010AUG31   -0.6719
10107   2010AUG31   -0.7056
...    ...            ...
10078   2015JUL30   -0.1651
10104   2015JUL30   0.1056
10107   2015JUL30   0.6181
10078   2015AUG31   -0.8886
10104   2015AUG31   0.6119
10107   2015AUG31   0.1056
```

I have searched the web extensively and tried this myself, but I feel really stuck on this problem. Thank you in advance for anyone who is able to help in any way.

UPDATE: Here is the modified code that I am using. Many thanks to user667489.

```
/*Join on the previous 6 months of data for each stock*/
proc sql;
create view rolling as
  select 
    a.PERMNO, /* PERMNO is the variable that identifies a stock */
    a.DATE as MONYR_A label="", /* DATE is a date variable for each daily return */
    b.DATE as MONYR_B label="",
    b.RET /* RET is the variable containing daily returns */
  from Dsex3 a left join Dsex3 b /* Dsex3 is the dataset that contains the identifiers for stocks and their daily returns */  
    on      a.PERMNO = b.PERMNO 
        and 1 <= intck('month',b.date,a.date) <= 6
  group by a.PERMNO, MONYR_A
  having count(*) >= 6 /*Only calculate skewness if we have at least 6 months of data*/
  order by a.PERMNO desc,MONYR_A,MONYR_B;
quit;


/*Calculate the skewness for the previous 6 months worth of data*/
ods listing close;
ods output moments=skewness_summary(
  keep = PERMNO MONYR_A label1 nvalue1
  where=(label1='Skewness')
  rename = (nvalue1 = skewness_6mth)
);
proc univariate data = rolling;
  var RET;
  by descending PERMNO MONYR_A;
run;
ods listing;
```

Comment: So what did you try?

Comment: I don't think any of the codes I tried to create were near what's needed.The main obstacle that I am facing is that I can't figure out how to calculate the rolling skewness measure from daily data, and put this as an output on a monthly basis. And to do this using the desired time window (previous 6 months).

Comment: Do you have a SAS/ETS licensed? If so, look into PROC EXPAND. Post the code you've used so we know what approaches you've tried and because SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have SAS/ETS, you could try something like this:

```
/*Generate some dummy data from the sashelp area*/
proc summary data = sashelp.prdsal2 nway;
  var ACTUAL;
  class COUNTRY STATE PRODUCT MONYR;
  output out = prdsal2(drop = _:) sum=;
run;

/*Join on the previous 6 months of data for each product*/
proc sql;
create view rolling as
  select 
    a.COUNTRY, 
    a.STATE, 
    a.PRODUCT, 
    a.MONYR as MONYR_A label="", 
    b.MONYR as MONYR_B label="", 
    b.ACTUAL
  from prdsal2 a left join prdsal2 b   
    on      a.COUNTRY = b.COUNTRY 
        and a.STATE   = b.STATE 
        and a.PRODUCT = b.PRODUCT
        and 1 <= intck('month',b.MONYR,a.MONYR) <= 6
  group by a.COUNTRY,a.STATE,a.PRODUCT,MONYR_A
  having count(*) >= 6 /*Only calculate skewness if we have at least 6 months of data*/
  order by a.COUNTRY desc,a.STATE,a.PRODUCT,MONYR_A,MONYR_B;
quit;

/*Calculate the skewness for the previous 6 months worth of data*/
ods listing close;
ods output moments=skewness_summary(
  keep = COUNTRY STATE PRODUCT MONYR_A label1 nvalue1 
  where=(label1='Skewness')
  rename = (nvalue1 = skewness_6mth)
);
proc univariate data = rolling;
  var ACTUAL;
  by descending COUNTRY STATE PRODUCT MONYR_A;
run;
ods listing;
```

I discovered that SAS has an actual `skewness` function that calculates it directly for a list of variables, so here's a data step approach as well:

```
/*Data step approach, using the skewness function*/
data skewness_summary2;
do _n_ = 1 by 1 until(last.MONYR_A);
  set rolling(keep = COUNTRY STATE PRODUCT MONYR_A ACTUAL);
  by descending COUNTRY STATE PRODUCT MONYR_A;
  skewness_6mth = skewness(ACTUAL,lag1(ACTUAL),lag2(ACTUAL),lag3(ACTUAL),lag4(ACTUAL),lag5(ACTUAL));
  if _n_ >= 6 then output;
end;
run;
```

The data step approach appears to be a bit faster than using proc univariate, probably because the proc is calculating all the other moments as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I modified the proc univariate approach code (in terms of variable and table names) for my dataset, and it appears to do exactly what I wanted. The only thing is that the code calculates a skewness measure for a stock that has less than 6 months of data available. For some reason, the line: having count(*) >= 6 does not appear to work as intended.

In terms of the data step approach, it indeed appears to be faster. Is there a way to modify that code to calculate the skewness from daily data for a monthly output (as in the proc univariate approach)?

Comment: It's possible to do something like that if you set up a hash object to keep track of the entries in the rolling window. I suggest you have a go.